# Yogam and Karnam

Tags: scripture, puranas, manu-smriti

I came to know there are 27 **Yogams** and 11 **Karnams**. Half a thithi is one karnam. In this too 7 karnams will move and 4 karnams will not. Are there any instances in smritis [manu] or puranas [any]or bagavatham about the importance and benefits of  yogam and karnam? Because when we do **sankalpa** these two find a place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 27 Nithyayogas
>
> 1) Vishkambha, 2) Preethi, 3) Ayushman, 4) Soubhagya, 5) Shobhana, 6) Athiganda, 7) Sukarma, 8) Dhrithi, 9) Soolam, 10) Ganda, 11) Vridhi, 12) Dhruva, 13) Vyaghatha, 14) Harshana, 15) Vajra, 16) Siddhi, 17) Vyathipatha, 18) Variyan, 19) Parigha, 20) Shiva, 21) Siddha, 22) Sadhya, 23) Subhra, 24) Braahma,  25) Mahendra, 26) Vaidhruthi, 27) Shubha

Their length, as the length of the stars, is 13 degree 20 minutes. Nithyayoga is the sum of the longitudes of Sun and Moon.

Karanam

Karanam is half of Tithi. There are 28 Tithis from Shukla Pradhama Uttarashada to Krishna Chathurdasi Purvashada. So there are 56 Karanams.

Charakaranas

> 1) Lion (Bava),   2) Tiger (Balava),  3)  Pig    (Koulava),   4)  Ass   (Taitila),  5)  Elephant (Gara),  6)  Cow  (Vanija),    7)  Vishti (Bhadra).

These 7 Charakaranas are repeated 8 times.

The four Karanas including Shukla Pradhama's Purvashada, Krishna Chathurdasi's Uttarashada and the two parts of Amavasi are permanent karanas. These come only once. They are 1) Bird (Sakuna) 2) Four-legged animal (Chatushpada)  3) Snake (Naga)  4) Worm (Kimstugna).

https://www.epanchang.com/daily-panchangam